# What is the difference between Collections.emptyList() vs Collections::emptyList

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

When using java stream show error while coding

```
Optional.ofNullable(product.getStudents())
                .orElseGet(Collections.emptyList())
                .stream().map(x->x.getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this code shows below error
**ERROR**

> incompactible type, Required Supplier> but
>   empty list was  interfered to List : no instance of type variable
>   of T exist so List conforms to Supplier>

But if I replace the `Collections.emptyList()` WITH `Collections::emptyList`
It will be perfect.

What is the difference between Collections.emptyList() vs Collections::emptyList?

Comment: short: first is an expression calling that method, second is a reference to that method (call is *delayed*, or eventually not called at all) BTW probably `x->x.getId()` could be susbstitued by `Student::getId` (assuming the the class of `x` and that `getId` is a method of it (typo in posted code?))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Collections.emptyList()` is a `static` method that returns a `List<T>`, i.e. the expression `Collections.emptyList()` will execute the `emptyList()` method and its value would be a `List<T>`. Therefore, you can only pass that expression to methods that require a `List` argument.

`Collections::emptyList` is a method reference, which can implement a functional interface whose single method has a matching signature.

A `Supplier<List<T>>` is a functional interface having a single method that returns a `List<T>`, which matches the signature of `Collections.emptyList()`. Therefore, a method - such as `Optional`'s `orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> other)` - that in your example requires a `Supplier<? extends List<Student>>` - can accept the method reference `Collections::emptyList`, which can implement that interface.

Comment: I would say that `Collections.emptyList()` is an expression calling that method and resulting in a `List`

Comment: @user85421 thanks for your comment. I expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

:: operator is shorthand for lambdas calling a specific method– by name. It is of course even more readable syntax.

It Can be used with static of instance method as well.

for static:
Collections::emptyList

for instance :
System.out::print